# Basic Spring MVC. HTTP 404 error. Tried all possible solutions

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am having trouble executing basic spring mvc application. I have tried all possible solutions and finally wanted to get this resolved. I don't want to create a new workspace and do it again. I wanted to get this working. Here is my [GitHub url](https://github.com/venkatmarepalli/BasicSpringMVC1.) for the project. I am landing on correct page (index.jsp).

I tried all these

1. `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`
2. `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>`
3. Tweaked `@RequestMapping` from method to class and by changing it from
   `(/welcome)` to `(value = "/welcome", method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})`

Sometimes I see `no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-in-dispatcherservlet-with-name` error in console and sometimes its nothing.

I know there are many similar questions out there, I have gone through lot of questions and started this new thread. My problem is

[image]

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>BasicSpringMVC1</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>basicspringmvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>basicspringmvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/test.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/test.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

basicspringmvc-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.basicSpringMvc1.controller" />
 <mvc:annotation-driven/>
   <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>BasicSpringMVC1</groupId>
  <artifactId>BasicSpringMVC1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

SpringHelloWorld.java

```
package com.basicSpringMvc1.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class SpringHelloWorld {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "<br><div style='text-align:center;'>"
                + "<h3>********** Hello World, Spring MVC Tutorial</h3>This message is coming from SpringHelloWorld.java **********</div><br><br>";
        return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);
    }
}
```

Project Structure

[image]

Comment: <servlet>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/basicspringmvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet> and  <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>..in wex.xml and try..

Comment: Only keep *.html in your servlet mapping and check your context name is BasicSpringMVC1 .

Comment: `Apr 22, 2017 10:48:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache` this is getting logged in Console instead of `Apr 22, 2017 4:26:23 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping register` . Can anyone throw some light on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that, in your servlet mapping:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

you have added url-pattern for `welcome.html`.
But your controllers' request mapping is set as `@RequestMapping("/welcome")`.

Either add url mapping for `/welcome`:
    `<servlet-mapping>
        <url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>` 

so that in can get mapped to your controller.
Or change the request mapping of your controller to `@RequestMapping("/welcome.html")` so that the controller get mapped to `welcome.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps!. Change the `servlet-mapping` entry in Web.xml to what is below. You have to avoid putting lot of `url-pattern` in your web.xml

```
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>basicspringmvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

then try this
    http://localhost:8080/BasicSpringMVC1/welcome.htm

Comment: This didn't help.

Comment: can you paste the log of the time when your spring application starts

Comment: Here is the console log [link](https://gist.github.com/venkatmarepalli/76a90fa7407bc3ffb8d3d5542effa66b)

Comment: After trying all possible solutions I figured out that mapping is not done, I don't see this message on the log. `INFO: Mapped "{[/welcome]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.....)` Not sure how to fix this.
`